# Using fuzzywuzzy to create a column of matched results in the data frame

Tags: python, pandas, fuzzywuzzy

I'm running into a challenge with using the FuzzyWuzzy library to store all my results in a data frame column (I'm guessing it might require a loop?) I've been scratching my head over this all day, now I want to see if any of you can help me with the solution! Would be super helpful!

---

As an example of what I'm trying to do, here's 2 data frame tables…

**Master Table**

```
+----+-----------------+
| ID |      ITEM       |
+----+-----------------+
|    |                 |
| 1  | Pepperoni Pizza |
|    |                 |
| 2  | Cheese Pizza    |
|    |                 |
| 3  | Chicken Salad   |
|    |                 |
| 4  | Plain Salad     |
+----+-----------------+
```

**Lookup Table**

```
+--------------+---+
| LOOKUP VALUE | - |
+--------------+---+
|              |   |
| Cheese       | - |
|              |   |
| Salad        | - |
+--------------+---+
```

Essentially I'm trying to use the lookup table's values against the entire list of values in the Master table, and store the results in a third table.

**Here's how I want the final output to look...**

```
+--------------+----------------------------+-------------------+
| LOOKUP VALUE |       MATCHED VALUES       | MATCHED VALUE IDS |
+--------------+----------------------------+-------------------+
|              |                            |                   |
| Cheese       | Cheese Pizza               | 2                 |
|              |                            |                   |
| Salad        | Chicken Salad, Plain Salad | 3,4               |
+--------------+----------------------------+-------------------+
```

I know the very basics of Fuzzy Wuzzy, here's how I started:

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
from fuzzywuzzy import process

choices = ["Pepperoni Pizza","Cheese Pizza","Chicken Salad", "Plain Salad"]
process.extract("salad",choices,limit=2)
```

**Output** = [('Chicken Salad', 90), ('Plain Salad', 90)]

Great, but how do you do that in a systematic way, running all my lookup values against all the values in the master table?

Thanks a ton for reading me out!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a good idea to store lists in DataFrame, I suggest store every match as a row in DataFrame. Here is the code:

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
from fuzzywuzzy import process

import pandas as pd
import io

master = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""ID,ITEM
1,Pepperoni Pizza
2,Cheese Pizza
3,Chicken Salad
4,Plain Salad"""))

lookups = ["Cheese", "Salad"]

choices = master.set_index("ID").ITEM.to_dict()

res = [(lookup,) + item for lookup in lookups for item in process.extract(lookup, choices,limit=2)]
df = pd.DataFrame(res, columns=["lookup", "matched", "score", "id"])
df
```

output:

```
   lookup        matched  score  id
0  Cheese   Cheese Pizza     90   2
1  Cheese  Chicken Salad     45   3
2   Salad  Chicken Salad     90   3
3   Salad    Plain Salad     90   4
```

Basically, I create a `choices` dict from `master` for match and then for loop the `lookups` and store the result as a list. And convert the list to DataFrame finally.

Comment: Thank you, this is PERFECT! 100% agree with you that a more tabular structure (as the one you gave me) is much better than inserting lists into a data frame (what was I thinking?). Thanks again this is super helpful for a Python beginner!!